# Connect 4 circles pattern in html 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

currently I have this code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jerred/2fnxtfr3/#&togetherjs=7eBvwmeThd)

which creates 4 circles then connect it to the last circle.

Here is the scenario which I need to implement:

Left Click on a region then it will be Point A.

Click on other region then it will be Point B.

Point A and B can be connected.

Add point C which will be connected to point A and B.

Add point D which will be connected to point B and C.

The points can be drag but still connected

How can I implement connecting the lines? and enables them to be drag

```
 function drawCircle(cx,cy){
 if(lastX){
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
 ctx.lineTo(cx,cy);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
 }

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fill();

 }

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  if(i<4)
  {
     i++;
     drawCircle(mx,my);
  }
  lastX=mx;
  lastY=my;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can test if the mouse is inside one of your circle-points like this:**

```
var dx=mouseX-circleCenterX;
var dy=mouseY-circleCenterY;
if(dx*dx+dy*dy<circleRadius*circleRadius){
    // the mouse is inside the circle
}
```

If the mouse is inside one of your lettered circles, then the user wants to drag that circle. So in mousemove, change the circle's position by the amount the mouse has moved since the last mousedown.

If the mouse is not inside one of your lettered circles, then the user wants to add a new circle. So add a new circle-point into an array that holds all of the user's circle-points.

**Example code:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var startX,startY;

var radius=5;
var nextLetter=65;
var anchors=[];
var connectors=[];
var draggingIndex=-1;
function addAnchor(x,y){
  anchors.push({
    label:String.fromCharCode(nextLetter),
    x:x,
    y:y,
  });
  nextLetter++;
}

draw();

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});


function draw(){

  //
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

  // draw connecting lines
  for(var i=0;i<connectors.length;i++){
    var c=connectors[i];
    var s=anchors[c.start];
    var e=anchors[c.end];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(s.x,s.y);
    ctx.lineTo(e.x,e.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }   

  // draw circles
  for(var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(anchors[i].x,anchors[i].y,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill(); 
    ctx.fillText(anchors[i].label,anchors[i].x-5,anchors[i].y-15); 
  }

}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  draggingIndex=-1;
  for(var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++){
    var a=anchors[i];
    var dx=startX-a.x;
    var dy=startY-a.y;
    if(dx*dx+dy*dy<radius*radius){
      draggingIndex=i;
      break;
    }
  }

  // If a drag hasn't started, add another anchor here
  if(draggingIndex==-1){
    addAnchor(startX,startY);
    if(anchors.length>1){
      connectors.push({
        start:anchors.length-2,
        end:anchors.length-1
      });
    }
    draw();
  }

}

function handleMouseUpOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  draggingIndex=-1;
}


function handleMouseMove(e){

  if(draggingIndex<0){return;}

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  var a=anchors[draggingIndex];
  a.x+=(mouseX-startX);
  a.y+=(mouseY-startY);
  startX=mouseX;
  startY=mouseY;          
  draw();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click to add points. Existing points are draggable.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: nice! but the only thing that I cant get is how to connect A to C and B to D

Comment: Just add connectors. For example, `connectors.push({start:0,end:2})` will connect anchors[0] & anchors[2] with a line. Since anchor[0] is 'A' and anchors[2] is 'C' that means A & C will be connected. ;-)

Comment: when I'm adding connectors.push the draw function is not called in some iteration

Comment: Correct, after `connectors.push` you will have to call the draw() function so that your new connector is drawn onto the canvas.

Comment: the labels and circle is only coming in the 'D' even though   draw();
      connectors.push({start:0,end:2});
      draw();
        connectors.push({start:1,end:2});
        draw();
        connectors.push({start:1,end:3});
        draw();

Comment: Well, connecting 1-to-2 is already being done as the user click-adds their points. Connecting 0-to-2 and 1-to-3 can only be done after there are at least 4 anchors. I have added to my example showing when & how to add the extra connectors.

Comment: Is it possible to omit the constraint of at least 4 anchors?

Comment: Not without unsightly logical manipulations. That's because you can't connect anchors that haven't been defined yet. But as long as any two anchors being connected have been defined, you can connect them anytime. So you could connect 0-to-2 as soon as anchors 0 & 2 exist. ;-)

Comment: My problem is the circle and label are gone after connecting 0-1, but it all returns after declaring (0,1,2,3)

Comment: Sorry, without your code I can't follow your issues, but here is an example that automatically creates connection 0-to-2 when 0 & 2 exist and automatically creates connection 1-to-3 when 1 & 3 exist. Good luck with your project! https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/r1u5Le2t/